# Некорректный вывод в матрице корреляций

Tags: python

Подскажите, пожалуйста:

Я строю матрицу корреляций кодом

```
s = stats.spearmanr(df)
sx, sy = s.correlation.shape
m = []
for y in range(sy):
    row = []
    for x in range(sx):
        z = f'{s.correlation[y,x]:.2f}'
        if s.pvalue[y,x] < 0.01:
            z += '**'
        elif s.pvalue[y,x] < 0.05:
            z += '*'
        row.append(z)
    m.append(row)

df_corr = pd.DataFrame(m)
df_corr.columns = df.columns
df_corr.index = df.columns
df_corr
data = pd.DataFrame(df_corr)
```

Но почему-то получаю кучу значений nan в матрице ([image: картинка 1]). При этом если по тем же самым данным отстроить тепловую матрицу, она получается нормальной (картинка 2).

Может быть, у меня что-то не так в коде, но понять что- пока не могу...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

П.С. может кто-нибудь знает, как на тепловую матрицу корреляций добавить обозначения уровня значимости корреляций или хотя бы просто убрать значения незначимых корреляций?

Доступ к данным: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kCQQbvMVMEP8lkd2fO7QjKiuRfJzWpDTB6lOm0BvAwE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Хорошо бы посмотреть на саму матрицу `s.correlation`, ну или на исходные данные.

Comment: Спасибо за отклик! В формате гугл-таблицы будет нормально?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас просто присутствуют `NaN` в исходных данных и по умолчанию эта функция выдаёт то поведение, которое вы наблюдаете. Если вы хотите игнорировать `NaN` и считать корреляцию только по имеющимся значениям, укажите это с помощью соответствующего параметра:

```
s = stats.spearmanr(df, nan_policy='omit')
```

Другие методы, считающие корреляцию, могут игнорировать `NaN` по умолчанию. Например, если взять `df.corr()`, то он посчитает корреляцию, проигнорировав значения `NaN`. Скорее всего тепловая карта рисуется с использованием именно этой функции.

Comment: Ох, спасибо огромное!